# Expected performance of Raspberry Pi as NAS with software RAID-1

Tags: usb, hard-drive, performance

What kind of performance can I expect from a Raspberry Pi 2 as a NAS with 2 External hard-drives as a software RAID-1?

I know that the Ethernet runs as a USB device so they all (Ethernet and 2 external HDDs) share a single USB bus.

I already have a setup like this and am wondering if I'm seeing the full potential when I run tests.

I have achieved the following through tests:

### SETUP:

Raspberry Pi 2 overclocked to “Medium” via `raspi-config`, 2 x Seagate Expansion 3TBytes external hard-drives

Software RAID level 1 setup using `mdadm`:

```
mdadm -Cv /dev/md1 -l1 -n2 /dev/sd[ab]2
```

File-system *ext4* type created with:

```
mkfs /dev/md0 -t ext4
```

Performance test against a Desktop PC running Ubuntu 12.04, connected with wired network.

Using `iperf`, Raspberry Pi as server:

```
$ iperf -c raspberrypi -t30
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-30.0 sec   300 MBytes  83.8 Mbits/sec
```

Write onto software RAID file system using `dd`on the Raspberry Pi

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile6 bs=4M count=75
314572800 bytes (315 MB) copied, 17.2022 s, 18.3 MB/s
```

Copy from/to software RAID file system using dd on raspberry pi

```
$ dd if=testfile6 of=testfile7 bs=4M
314572800 bytes (315 MB) copied, 35.2339 s, 8.9 MB/s
```

I then exported the RAID drive as a NFS and made write tests on the Desktop PC after having mounted the NFS. Again, using `dd`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile8 bs=4M count=75
314572800 bytes (315 MB) copied, 50,9384 s, 6,2 MB/s
```

And a read test using `dd`:

```
$ dd if=testfile9 of=/dev/null bs=4M
314572800 bytes (315 MB) copied, 57,3728 s, 5,5 MB/s
```

I guess that writing to the software RAID over NFS require writing data to both external HDDs and an equal bandwidth share goes to the Ethernet controller.

However, if I can write directly to the software RAID with a speed of 18.3 MB/s which is the speed of writing all data twice, then I would expect an actual bandwidth of double that, i.e. 36.6 MB/s.

This bandwidth should be divided by 3 when data comes from the Ethernet controller meaning I should be able to transfer at (36.6 / 3) MB/s = 12.2 MB/s.

The `iperf` test showed that the Ethernet controller is able to transfer at 83.8 MBits/s = 10.4 MB/s so I guess this is the bottleneck, but then, why do I only get around 6 MB/s?

Comment: If you want legitmate times not influenced by the file cache you should `sudo sync` after writing a file and drop the caches before reading one (`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, but you must do that `su root`, `sudo` will not work).

Comment: Not like the RPi has much ram for file caches anyways...  to drop the caches easily, try this:  `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null`, no `su` required.